# Use iconv API in C

Tags: unicode, shift-jis

I try to convert a sjis string to utf-8 using the iconv API. I compiled it already succesfully, but the output isn't what I expected.
My code:

```
void convertUtf8ToSjis(char* utf8, char* sjis){
  iconv_t icd;
  int index = 0;
  char *p_src, *p_dst;
  size_t n_src, n_dst;
  icd = iconv_open("Shift_JIS", "UTF-8");
  int c;
  p_src = utf8;
  p_dst = sjis;
  n_src = strlen(utf8);
  n_dst = 32; // my sjis string size
  iconv(icd, &p_src, &n_src, &p_dst, &n_dst);
  iconv_close(icd);
}
```

I got only random numbers. Any ideas?

Edit:
My input is

```
char utf8[] = "\xe4\xba\x9c";       //亜
```

And output should be: 
0x88 0x9F

But is in fact:
0x30 0x00 0x00 0x31 0x00 ...

Comment: What are your input and output?

Comment: Thank you - I added input & output to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to duplicate the problem. The only thing I can suggest is to be careful about your allocations.

#### Code:

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void convertUtf8ToSjis(char* utf8, char* sjis){
 ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char utf8[] = "\xe4\xba\x9c";
  char *sjis;
  sjis = malloc(32);
  convertUtf8ToSjis(utf8, sjis);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; sjis[i]; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x\n", (unsigned char)sjis[i]);
  }
  free(sjis);
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ gcc t.c
$ ./a.out
88
9f
```

Comment: It's great to know, that there's no mistake in my function itself. I will check all allocations and search the problem there - thank you very much and have a great christmas!

Comment: Hello Constantin.. This code is working fine if the UTF-8 string doesn't have spaces. But when i tested with spaces in between the characters, it does not converting the next characters which are there after the spaces.